# Browser compatibility with Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, html, browser, microsoft-edge

I'm currently facing an interesting "bug".

I have a website where I import my JS scripts in the header.

And in one of them I call document.body.append(), it works with Chrome, Firefox, Safari, InternetExplorer but Microsoft Edge.

With Edge I get null on document.body .

What could cause this if all the other browser works perfectly?

Comment: It's caused either by a bug in your code or a bug in Edge.

Comment: Actually a lot of things can cause this. Please provide a [MCVE]